# I'm getting this error in my simulator when trying to render React Native app

Tags: react-native

This is my first time using react native. I am following a tutorial but my results are different than the tutorial. I've triple checked my code and its exactly as its shown but I'm getting this error. Any ideas?

```
// Import a library to help create a Component

import React from 'react';
import { Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

// Create a Component
const App = () => (
    <Text>Some Text</Text>
);

// Render it to the device
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
```

The error is

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

```
Check the render method of `AwakeInDevApp`.
    in AwakeInDevApp (at registerRootComponent.js:21)
    in ExponentRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:128)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:93)
    in RCTView (at View.js:128)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

[Screenshot of Error in Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYLE2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 'albums' to 'AwakeInDevApp', it must be your project name when you run `react-native init YourProjectName`